# Regex matching a word not followed by a string and allow multiple words (upto 5 words) in between

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a word ("Junior Consultant") not followed by a specific string "(m/f)" and allow multiple words (up to 5 words) in between.

Should match:

`Junior Consultant in New York
Junior Consultant Banking
Junior Consultant w1 w2 w3 w4 w5
Junior Consultant w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 (m/f)`

Should NOT match:

`Junior Consultant in New York (m/f)
Junior Consultant (m/f)
Junior Consultant w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 (m/f)`

This is what I got so far:
`Junior Consultant((?!\s\(m\/f\))(\s\w+)){0,5}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there, but you have to match all zero to five words before the "(m/f)" part. Try this:

```
/Junior Consultant(?!(\s\w+){0,5}\s\(m\/f\))/
```

Comment: Thank so much for the fast reply. My sanity is back to normal now :)